# Unable to resize 1/6 css grid into 2 /2 css grid with media query

Tags: html, css, media-queries, css-grid

I'm building a footer that is supposed to have:

- 4x1 grid on a small screen
- 2x2 grid on medium screen
- 1x4 grid on the    biggest screen

I am successful with small and large design, however and cant not find a way to change the grid for medium screens.

Where am I going wrong?

Html as below:

```
<div class="parent">
    <b></b>
    <div class="intro">
        Some content goes here
    </div>
    <div class="col1">
        Some content goes here
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
        Some content goes here
    </div>
    <div class="col3">
        Some content goes here
    </div>
    <b></b>
</div>
```

My CSS code is as below:

```
.parent {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(6, max-content);
    grid-template-areas:
                    '.'
                    'intro'
                    'col1'
                    'col2'
                    'col3'
                    '.';

    @media screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 599px) {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 150px 150px 1fr;
        //grid-template-rows: auto auto;
        grid-template-areas:
                      '. intro col1 .'
                      '. col2  col3 .';
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr repeat(4, minmax(50ch, 70ch)) 1fr;
        grid-template-areas: '. intro col1 col2 col3 .';
    }
}
```

Comment: You have an error in `min-width: 400px` - your `.col1` is in twice. Should one of those be `.col2`?

Comment: Put a lower as well as higher limit on the medium sized query. `(min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 599px)`. This should be specific enough.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in this particular case when 1 row grid with empty areas is converted into 2 rows grid with empty areas, child elements have to be explicitly assigned with area names. Otherwise the content will not be displayed properly.

```
.intro { grid-area: intro;}
.col1 { grid-area: col1;}
.col2 { grid-area: col2;}
.col3 { grid-area: col3;}
```